# Curious ODE with Dirac comb

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dirac-delta

I got stuck in my calculations trying to solve the following problem:

> Given the ODE $$\dot{x} = -\alpha x + a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\delta(t-n\tau)$$ where $\alpha \gt 0$, define $$x_k = x(k\tau +0 )$$ and find $x_k$ as a function of $x_{k-1}$.
> What is the value of the following limit $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}x_k?$$

### My attempt

First of all we define the following function

$$f(t) = a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\delta(t-n\tau)$$ then the ODE becomes pretty much standard $$\dot{x}(t) = -\alpha x(t) + f(t)$$

for which the general solution is

$$x(t) = e^{-\alpha t} x(0)+\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-t')}f(t')\,dt'\\ x(t) = e^{-\alpha t} x(0)+\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-t')}a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\delta(t'-n\tau)\,dt'.$$

Now we interchange the sum with the integral (being a physicist I impudently change them without checking uniform convergence!) and get

$$x(t)= e^{-\alpha t} x(0)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a\int_0^t e^{-\alpha(t-t')}\delta(t'-n\tau)\,dt'$$

By the definition of $x_k$

$$\begin{align}x_k = x(k\tau+0) &=  e^{-\alpha k\tau} x(0)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a\int_0^{k\tau} e^{-\alpha(k\tau-t')}\delta(t'-n\tau)\,dt'\\&=\underbrace{e^{-\alpha k\tau}x(0)}_{\text{first term}}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^kae^{-\alpha(k\tau-n\tau)}}_{\text{second term}}\end{align}$$

We can easily calculate $x_{k-1}$ from the value of $x_k$

$$ x_{k-1} =  \underbrace{e^{-\alpha(k-1)\tau}x(0)}_{\text{first term}}+\underbrace{a\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}e^{-\alpha(k\tau-n\tau)}}_{\text{second term}}.$$

It is clear that is we want to make a relation between $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$, the first terms of both can be written as $$e^{-\alpha k\tau}x(0) = e^{-\alpha\tau}e^{-\alpha(k-1)\tau}x(0)$$ so I'm bound to say that, at list for the first terms $$x_k = e^{-\alpha\tau}x_{k-1}\tag2$$ The real problem arises when we try to make adjustments to $(2)$ to make the second terms equal, mainly from definition $(2)$ we get

$$x_k = e^{-\alpha\tau}e^{-\alpha(k-1)\tau}x(0) + \color{red}{e^{-\alpha\tau}a\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}e^{-\alpha(k-n)\tau}}$$

My questions now are

> **Question 1:** How can I adjust that second term to get $x_k$ as a function of $x_{k-1}$?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: When you plug in what $f(t')$ is, shouldn't it be $\delta(t'-n\tau)?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Sure should! I'll correct it thanks!

Comment: I don't think it affects future steps - it looks like you've used the Dirac Delta property correctly there.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yeah in my calculations there was a $t'$ only to differentiate the variable of integration from the upper index of the integral, just forgot to add it here, mathjax can be pretty confusing at times!

Comment: @DavideMorgante MathJax isn't *that* bad, but it helps if you use a lot of white space for readability.  For example, putting empty lines above and below displayed equations helps.  Using newlines in aligned environments also helps.  I edited your question to fix a couple of little grammar errors, but cleaned up your MathJax a little while I was under the hood.  I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Several typos: first, the prefactor of $x(0)$ in $x(t)$ is $e^{-at}$, not $e^{at}$; second, you forgot to replace $t$ by $k\tau$ in the second terms of $x_k$, thus missing the simplifications that follow. I believe that if you modify your try with respect to these two points, everything should run smoothly afterwards...

Comment: I think your (2) is suspect. There has to be an additive relationship between $x_k$ and $x_{k-1},$ because the $x_{k-1}$ exponential sum doesn't go as far as the $x_k$ one does.I would write $$x_k=e^{\alpha\tau}e^{\alpha(k-1)\tau}x(0)+a\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}e^{-\alpha(t-n\tau)}+ae^{-\alpha(t-k\tau)}.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for the correction in the definition of $x_k$. For the exponent of the exponential I thought that it would be $e^{-at}$ in the case if the equation $$\dot{x} = ax+f$$ in my case $a=-\alpha$ so $-a=\alpha$. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Did No, you're certainly right $$x=e^{-\alpha t}\implies \dot{x} = -\alpha e^{-\alpha t} = -\alpha x$$. That's a terrible error!

Comment: "Is that not the case?" No. As a way to memorize this, simply note that $y'=by$ is solved by $y(t)=y(0)e^{bt}$, for every $b$, thus, in the absence of $f$, your equation would read $x'=-\alpha x$ and be solved by $x(t)=x(0)e^{-\alpha t}$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I'm thinking about it! I'll come back when if I've some better insights!

Comment: @DavideMorgante: Right. Note that what I wrote has to be modified by Did's correction.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes! I'm even editing the post for reference, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's start from 
$$x_k(\tau) = x(k\tau)= e^{-\alpha k\tau}x(0)+a\sum_{n=0}^ke^{-\alpha\tau(k-n)}.$$
Then
$$x_{k-1}(\tau)=e^{-\alpha (k-1)\tau}x(0)+a\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}e^{-\alpha\tau((k-1)-n)}.$$
In comparing the two, we want to get $x_k$ to look like $x_{k-1}.$ So we write
\begin{align*}x_k(\tau) &= e^{-\alpha\tau}e^{-\alpha (k-1)\tau}x(0)+a\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}e^{-\alpha\tau(k-n)}+a \\
&=e^{-\alpha\tau}e^{-\alpha (k-1)\tau}x(0)+ae^{-\alpha\tau}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}e^{-\alpha\tau((k-1)-n)}+a \\
&=e^{-\alpha\tau}x_{k-1}(\tau)+a.\end{align*}

To compute the limit, I would figure exactly what $x_{0}(\tau)$ is (looks like $x_0(\tau)=x(0)+a$), then write $x_{k}(\tau)$ in terms of that. That's something you could take the limit of.

Comment: Great! Simple and ingenious. I was very close to it! Thank you very much for the help, I've greatly appreciated

Comment: @DavideMorgante: Yes, I'd agree: you certainly did the heavy lifting here.